# Много баллунов на яндекс картах

Tags: карты, php, yandex-maps-api

У автосалона проставляется город. И при выборе марки машины на карте должно быть показан список с адресами автосалонов и отмечаные на карте места расположения автосалов.
Вот вывод адресов автосалов, он же и проставляется в яндекс карты по идеи. Но все места забиваются в один баллун(Balloon).

```
<?
    $city=$_GET['city'];

    $id=$_GET['label_id'];

    if(!$_GET['label_id']) $id='ololo';
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php');
    define("STOP_STATISTICS", true);
    if (CModule::IncludeModule('iblock'))
    {
        $dbRes = CIBlockElement::GetList(
            Array(
                "SORT"=>"ASC",
                "PROPERTY_PRIORITY"=>"ASC" 
            ),
            Array(
                'IBLOCK_ID' => 19,
                'PROPERTY_AUTO_LABELS' => $id,
                'PROPERTY_CITY' => $city
            ),
            false,
            false,
            Array('ID','NAME', 'PROPERTY_ADDRESS')
        );
while($arRes = $dbRes->GetNext())
{
  echo $city." ".$arRes['PROPERTY_ADDRESS_VALUE']."<br />";
}
        /*if ($arRes = $dbRes->Fetch())
        {
            echo "$city ";
            echo $arRes['PROPERTY_ADDRESS_VALUE'];
        }
        else
            ShowError('Ничего не найдено'); */
    }
    else
        ShowError('Ошибка: не установлены инфоблоки.');
?>
```

А вот вывод вывод на странице списка адресов и сами карты соответственно.

```
 <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
 $APPLICATION->SetTitle("Контактная информация в Нижнем Новгороде"); ?>
 <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?key=5465465к5рарпар45н45н45-lG_XTjbQ=="
    type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function get_mark() {
         var mark = $('#mark').val();

         var city = 'Новгород';

         $('#search_result').load('/contacts/get_address.php?label_id=' + mark + '&city=' + city, {}, function () {
             var content = $('#search_result').html();

             var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder(content); // THIS! IS! АДРЕС!!!
             YMaps.Events.observe(geocoder, geocoder.Events.Load, function (geocoder) {
                 var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), {
                     style: style
                 });
                 map.setCenter(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), 50);
                 placemark.description = "<span  class='underline'>Автосалон</span> br>Адрес: " + content;
                 map.addOverlay(placemark);
             });
         });
     }
 </script>

 <h1>Контактная информация в Новгороде</h1>

 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:breadcrumb", "agat1", array(
    "START_FROM" => "0",
    "PATH" => "",
    "SITE_ID" => "-"
    ),
    false
 );?>

 <div></div>

 <h2>Выберите марку автомобиля:</h2>
 <select class='select_auto_c' id='mark'>
     <?foreach($arResult["BRANDS"] as $key => $brand):?>
         <option value="<?=$brand["ID"]?>"
     <?if($brand["SELECTED"] == "Y") echo "selected";?>><?=$brand["NAME"]?></option>
     <?endforeach;?>
 </select>

 &nbsp;
 &nbsp;
 &nbsp;
 &nbsp;

 <a class="b b2" onClick="get_mark();"><em>Найти дилера</em></a>
 <br />
 <br />
 <div id='search_result'>* Выберите марку авто и нажмите Найти дилера, на  карту будут выведены адреса  автосалонов</div>
 <br />
 <div class='map_bg'>
 <div id="YMapsID" class> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
             window.onload = function () {
                 self.map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID"));
                 map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(44.515942, 48.707793), 50);
                 map.addControl(new YMaps.SmallZoom());
                 map.addControl(new YMaps.ToolBar());
                 map.addControl(new YMaps.TypeControl());

                 function SampleBalloonLayout() {
                     this.element = YMaps.jQuery("<div class=\"ballooooon\"><div  class=\"content\"></div><div  class=\"close\">x</div> div  class=\"tail\"></div></div>");

                     this.close = this.element.find(".close");
                     this.content = this.element.find(".content");

                     // Отключает кнопку закрытия балуна
                     this.disableClose = function () {
                         this.close.unbind("click").css("display", "none");
                     };

                     // Включает кнопку закрытия балуна
                     this.enableClose = function (callback) {
                         this.close.bind("click", callback).css("display", "");
                         return false;
                     };

                     // Добавляет макет на страницу
                     this.onAddToParent = function (parentNode) {
                         YMaps.jQuery(parentNode).append(this.element);
                     };

                     // Удаляет макет со страницы
                     this.onRemoveFromParent = function () {
                         this.element.remove();
                     };

                     // Устанавливает содержимое балуна
                     this.setContent = function (content) {
                         content.onAddToParent(this.content[0]);
                     };

                     // Обновляет балун
                     this.update = function () {};
                 };

                 self.sampleBalloonTemplate = new
                  YMaps.LayoutTemplate(SampleBalloonLayout);

                 self.style = new YMaps.Style();
                 style.balloonStyle = {
                     template: sampleBalloonTemplate
                 };

                 style.iconStyle = new YMaps.IconStyle();

                 style.iconStyle.href = "/images/pin.png";
                 style.iconStyle.size = new
                  YMaps.Point(24, 44);
                 style.iconStyle.offset = new
                  YMaps.Point(-12, -51);

                 style.iconStyle.shadow = new
                  YMaps.IconShadowStyle();
                 style.iconStyle.shadow.href = "/images/shadow_pin.png";
                 style.iconStyle.shadow.size = new
                  YMaps.Point(29, 35);
                 style.iconStyle.shadow.offset = new
                  YMaps.Point(-7, -38);

                 var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder("Новгород"); //
                 THIS!IS!АДРЕС !! !

                 YMaps.Events.observe(geocoder, geocoder.Events.Load, function (geocoder) {
                     map.setCenter(geocoder.get(0).getGeoPoint(), 50);
                 });

                 }
            </script>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php")?>
```

Comment: Вот тут вам быстрее помогут: <a href="http://clubs.ya.ru/mapsapi/">mapsapi on ya.ru</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте организовывать вывод через xml ?